# How to implement property delegate that works with an arbitrary type

Tags: kotlin, generics, types, delegates

I'm trying to implement custom property delegate to store props in a Map (just like in [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#storing-properties-in-a-map), for the educational purposes)

Delegate implementation must:

1. allow to store properties of arbitrary type
2. allow for type inference (just like the original one)

I've wrote a code that satisfies first condition:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty

fun main() {
    val e = Example(PropInMapDelegate())
    e.myProp = 1;
    println(e.myProp) // e.myProp is "Any?" :(
}

class Example(propInMapDelegate: PropInMapDelegate) {
    var myProp by propInMapDelegate
}

class PropInMapDelegate {
    private val _map: HashMap<String, Any?> = HashMap()

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>): Any? {
        return _map[property.name]
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>, value: Any?) {
        _map[property.name] = value
    }

}
```

But, it has obvious 2 issues:

1. Using "Any?" breaks type inference
2. Explicitly specifying property type `var myProp: Int by propInMapDelegate` leads to errors:

error#1

```
Property delegate must have a 'getValue(Example, KProperty*>)' method. None of the following functions are suitable.
getValue(Any?, KProperty<*>) defined in PropInMapDelegate
```

error#2

```
Property delegate must have a 'setValue(Example, KProperty*>, Int)' method. None of the following functions are suitable.
setValue(Any?, KProperty<*>, Any?) defined in PropInMapDelegate
```

I've tried to employ generics to allow for type inference, but failed.

Changing `PropInMapDelegate` implementation like so:

```
class PropInMapDelegate {
    private val _map: HashMap<String, Any?> = HashMap()

    operator fun <T>getValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>): T? {
        return _map[property.name] as T // That feels very wrong
    }

    operator fun <T>setValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>, value: T?) {
        _map[property.name] = value
    }

}
```

And using the following

```
class Example(propInMapDelegate: PropInMapDelegate) {
    var myProp: Int by propInMapDelegate // error (see below)
}
```

Leads to:
error#1

```
Property delegate must have a 'getValue(Example, KProperty*>)' method. None of the following functions are suitable.
getValue(Any, KProperty<*>)   where T = Int for    operator fun <T> getValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>): T? defined in PropInMapDelegate
```

error#2

```
Property delegate must have a 'setValue(Example, KProperty*>, Int)' method. None of the following functions are suitable.
setValue(Any, KProperty<*>, Int?)   where T = Int for    operator fun <T> setValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>, value: T?): Unit defined in PropInMapDelegate
```

Questions:

1. What am I missing?
2. Why does Kotlin expect the exact "Example" type in setValue/getValue signature?
3. How to implement "getValue" without using unsafe "as T" operator?
   Edit: it seems that original implementation utilizes `as` too, so it's probably ok?

```
public inline operator fun <V, V1 : V> MutableMap<in String, out @Exact V>.getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): V1 =
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") (getOrImplicitDefault(property.name) as V1)
```

Comment: You know you can look at the source code of the standard library to see how they did it?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried using inspect function to look it up, but ctrl+clicking on Map opens `interface Map` declaration and not the actual implementation, so I'm kinda at a loss

Comment: Ctrl click the `by` keyword where you have used it as a delegate to jump to the source, which is an extension function.

Comment: Thanks, inspecting `by` leads to corresponding `getValue` and `setValue` implementations, and I see my  3rd questions answered (original implementation utilizes `as` as well). But I cannot grasp the answer to the 2nd question from the source itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error message is misleading you because of the way it is worded. "Example" isn't the part that doesn't match. Since `Example` is a subtype of `Any`, that part of your `getValue()` function signature is fine.

The part that doesn't match is that you are returning `T?` but you're trying to use it for a non-nullable property.

If you change your property to be nullable, it will work:

```
var myProp: Int? by propInMapDelegate
```

Or if you change your operator function to return a non-nullable, it will work:

```
operator fun <T> getValue(thisRef: Any, property: KProperty<*>): T {
    return _map[property.name] as T
}
```

Note that casting `as T` will fail if the value for that key doesn't exist in the map and you're using this for a non-nullable property, because `null` cannot be cast to a non-nullable T.

Regarding your question marked 3: As you can see in the standard library source code, casting is unavoidable if you are using a map of arbitrary value types. It's part of the potential danger in using a map for this purpose. It is also possible the map doesn't have the values at all that match up with the requested property names.

Comment: It is misleading indeed.

Comment: Passing using `Int?` works, but that means I'll be forced to use nullable counterparts of types. Instead, I got rid of `T?` in favor of just `T` in `PropInMapDelegate` implementation. It works with both nullable and non-nullable types, but then your statement "`null` cannot be cast to a non-nullable T." does not hold, since I can set `null` and get that property value just fine. Any idea why does it work? https://controlc.com/9d7386c2

Comment: By non-nullable T, I mean when T is a non-nullable type. A generic type can represent a nullable type even without a question mark.